# Preventing HttpClient 4 from following redirect

Tags: android, google-app-engine, apache-commons

I'm connecting to my AppEngine application using the Apache HttpComponents library.  In order to authenticate my users, I need to pass an authentication token along to the application's login address (http://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/login?auth=...) and grab a cookie from the header of the response.  However, the login page responds with a redirect status code, and I don't know how to stop HttpClient from following the redirect, thus thwarting me from intercepting the cookie.

Fwiw, the actual method I use to send the request is below.

```
private void execute(HttpClient client, HttpRequestBase method) {
    // Set up an error handler
    BasicHttpResponse errorResponse = new BasicHttpResponse(
            new ProtocolVersion("HTTP_ERROR", 1, 1), 500, "ERROR");

    try {
        // Call HttpClient execute
        client.execute(method, this.responseHandler);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        errorResponse.setReasonPhrase(e.getMessage());
        try {
            this.responseHandler.handleResponse(errorResponse);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // log and/or handle
        }
    }
}
```

How would I stop the client from following the redirect?

Thanks.

**Update**:

As per the solution below, I did the following after creating a `DefaultHttpClient client` (and before passing it to the `execute` method):

```
if (!this.followRedirect) {
    client.setRedirectHandler(new RedirectHandler() {
        public URI getLocationURI(HttpResponse response,
                HttpContext context) throws ProtocolException {
            return null;
        }

        public boolean isRedirectRequested(HttpResponse response,
                HttpContext context) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

More verbose than it seems it needs to be, but not as difficult as I thought.

Comment: Note that once you have set a RedirectHandler that remains in effect for all subsequent Requests - not just the Request of interest here. So if you are are going on to issue further Requests which may require redirection to execute properly you will want to do a client.setRedirectHandler(new DefaultRedirectHandler()) after the execute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a [`RedirectHandler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/RedirectHandler.html). That may require extending [`DefaultHttpClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) to return your custom implementation from `createRedirectHandler()`.

Comment: If you are using the amazing android-async-http library, I created a fork + pull request of it that has this behaviour: https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/pull/184

Answer (score 30):

You can do it with the http params:

```
final HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);
```

The method has no javadoc, but if you look at the source you can see it sets:

[HANDLE_REDIRECTS](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/params/ClientPNames.html#HANDLE_REDIRECTS)

which controls:

> Defines whether redirects should be handled automatically

Answer (score 10):

With the Version 4.3.x of HttpClient its directly in the [clientBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html).

so when u build your Client use:

```
CloseableHttpClient client = clientBuilder.disableRedirectHandling().build();
```

I know its an old question but I had this problem too and want to share my solution.

Answer (score 1):

The [RedirectHandler](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/RedirectHandler.html) seem to be deprecated, I managed to disable automatically following the redirect responses by changing the default RedirectionStrategy for the DefaultHttpClient liks this:

```
httpClient.setRedirectStrategy(new RedirectStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean isRedirected(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpResponse httpResponse, HttpContext httpContext) throws ProtocolException {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public HttpUriRequest getRedirect(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpResponse httpResponse, HttpContext httpContext) throws ProtocolException {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

On the downside, this tie us to a specific implementation of the HttpClient but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

a quick google presented: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/redirects.html

Comment: Thanks for checking, but the link is for HttpClient 3.  My issue is that I'm writing an Android application, and Android comes with HttpClient 4.  Indeed, if I were using the Commons (3.x) HttpClient, I could just call setFollowRedirects(false) on my HttpMethod and be done with it.  As far as I can tell (and someone please correct me if I'm wrong), it's a little more complicated (if possible?) with HttpComponents.