# How to prevent apache http client from following a redirect

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm connecting to a remote server with apache http client. the remote server sends a redirect, and i want to achieve that my client isn't following the redirect automatically so that i can extract the propper header and do whatever i want with the target.

i'm looking for a **simple working code sample** (copy paste) **that stops the automatic redirect following behaviour**.

i found [Preventing HttpClient 4 from following redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352949/preventing-httpclient-4-from-following-redirect), but it seems i'm too stupid to implement it with HttpClient 4.0 (GA)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The default `HttpClient` implementation is pretty limited in configurability, but you can control the redirect handling by using HttpClient's boolean parameter `http.protocol.handle-redirects`.

See the [docs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/tutorial/html/httpagent.html#d5e1169) for reference.

Comment: a simple example of this [can be found here](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-stop-follow-redirect)

Comment: As of 4.3 this answer is deprecated, use use answer by David Riccitelli

Comment: @DSchmidt, the new API configures the entire client with this redirect behavior – not just the individual request. I want my client to disable an individual request, and it is achievable via pre 4.3 API.

Comment: not this, but answer of David Riticelli is the current (>= 4.3) proper solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21560006/1915920

Answer (score 49):

The magic, thanks to [macbirdie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5049/macbirdie) , is:

```
params.setParameter("http.protocol.handle-redirects",false);
```

Imports are left out, here's a copy paste sample:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

// HTTP parameters stores header etc.
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter("http.protocol.handle-redirects",false);

// Create a local instance of cookie store
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

// Bind custom cookie store to the local context
localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

// connect and receive 
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost/web/redirect");
httpget.setParams(params);
response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);

// obtain redirect target
Header locationHeader = response.getFirstHeader("location");
if (locationHeader != null) {
    redirectLocation = locationHeader.getValue();
  System.out.println("loaction: " + redirectLocation);
} else {
  // The response is invalid and did not provide the new location for
  // the resource.  Report an error or possibly handle the response
  // like a 404 Not Found error.
}
```

Comment: this is outdated use answer by David Riccitelli

Answer (score 31):

Using HttpClient 4.3 and Fluent:

```
final String url = "http://...";
final HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
    .disableRedirectHandling()
    .build();
final Executor executor = Executor.newInstance(client);
final HttpResponse response = executor.execute(Request.Get(url))
    .returnResponse();
```

Comment: Pertinent information: `HttpClientBuilder.create().disableRedirectHandling().build();`

Comment: Hey, nice answer. Is there a way to disable redirect for one specific request? It is achievable via request.setParams, but I don't know how to do it in httpclient version after 4.3.

Comment: Looking to do the exact same thing as @FanJin. Can someone please provide the answer to his question?

Comment: I was following the answer from this to address the exact issue. Just a side note, the .jar file to be imported to use Executor is httpclient JAR 4.5.1. https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.hynnet/httpclient/4.5.1/source-code. I've used fluent-hc-4.2-alpha1.jar initially and it didn't work. Just a heads up to anyone reading this.

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("www.google.com");
HttpParams params = httpGet.getParams();
params.setParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, Boolean.FALSE);
httpGet.setParams(params);
```

Comment: Worked for me perfectly and needed only minimal changes in code. Thanks.

Comment: `httpGet.getParams()` @deprecated (4.3) use {@link org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig}

Answer (score 12):

Rather than use the property directly you can use:

```
final HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);
```

Comment: `HttpClientParams` @deprecated (4.3) use {@link org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig}

Answer (score 2):

**Before HttpClient 4.3**

In older versions of the Http Client (before 4.3), we can configure what the client does with redirects as follows:

```
@Test
public void givenRedirectsAreDisabled_whenConsumingUrlWhichRedirects_thenNotRedirected() 
  throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    DefaultHttpClient instance = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, false);
    // HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false); // alternative

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http:/testabc.com");
    httpGet.setParams(params);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = instance.execute(httpGet);

    assertThat(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), equalTo(301));
}
```

Notice the alternative API that can be used to configure the redirect behavior **without using setting the actual raw http.protocol.handle-redirects parameter:**

```
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);
```

Also notice that, with follow redirects disabled, we can now check that the Http Response status code is indeed 301 Moved Permanently – as it should be.

**After HttpClient 4.3**

HttpClient 4.3 introduced a cleaner, **more high level API** to build and configure the client:

```
@Test
public void givenRedirectsAreDisabled_whenConsumingUrlWhichRedirects_thenNotRedirected() 
  throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpClient instance = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableRedirectHandling().build();
    HttpResponse response = instance.execute(new HttpGet("http://testabc.com"));

    assertThat(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), equalTo(301));
}
```

Note that the new API configures the entire client with this redirect behavior – not just the individual request.
Reference: http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-stop-follow-redirect

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me
`CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().disableRedirectHandling().build()`

Answer (score 0):

```
GetMethod method = new GetMethod(url);
method.setFollowRedirects(false);
```

Comment: at least in v4.5.2 there is no `GetMethod` anymore, but it was there in v3: https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/GetMethod.html

Answer (score 0):

To avoid automatic redirection header, one must first configure the request to not do automatic redirects. You can do this by calling `HttPClientParams.setRedirection` and set it to `false`. Code snippet is shown below:

```
HttpPost postURL = new HttpPost(resourceURL);
...
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(postURL.getParams(), false);
```

Comment: `HttpClientParams.setRedirecting` @deprecated (4.3) use {@link org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig}

Answer (score 0):

instead of call HttpClientBuilder directly, you can use

```
HttpClients.custom().disableRedirectHandling().build();
```

Comment: why would this be better?