# HttpClient with redirect

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent apache http client from following a redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519392/how-to-prevent-apache-http-client-from-following-a-redirect)

I am making a request using httpclient and after receiving the response, I get automatically redirected to another page. How can I stop this from happening?

Here are some more details:

I am trying to get a token from Google using oAuth2.0. I make the request for the token from the server using httpclient, but because of the `redirect_uri` I get somehow redirected. How can I stop this?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I do not think it is a duplicate. Maybe I don't understand the other question/answers, but I have tried to implement the code provided there and it did not work. Do you have another solution?

Comment: @Dragos The final answer on the page pointed to by TomaszNurkiewicz gives a working solution.