# Expecting status code between 300 to 400 but getting 200 android httpclient

Tags: android, redirect, android-webview, httpclient

I am trying to detect `redirected` page on android `webview`. After alot of effort , I found that status code for redirected page lies in between 300 and 400. I also checked status code for redirected page "en.m.wikipedia.com/wiki/Automobile" and got the desired result.
But I am trying to replicate samething in Android webview.I don't get 30X but get 200.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
   private WebView webView;
   private myWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient;
   private myWebViewClient mWebViewClient;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

       mWebViewClient = new myWebViewClient();
       webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);

       // mWebChromeClient = new myWebChromeClient();
      //  webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

      String url ="http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Automobile";
      webView.loadUrl(url);


}
  class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        Log.v("url loaded "," "+url);

        try{
            HttpClient httpClient;
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
            Log.w("Response ","Status line : "+    response.getStatusLine().toString());

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

       return false;  
    }
}
}
```

Here is my output:

```
 V/ url loaded: http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Automobile
 W/Response: Status line : HTTP/1.0 200 OK
 url loaded: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automobile
 Response: Status line : HTTP/1.0 200 OK
 url loaded: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automobile
 Response: Status line : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Apache DefaultHttpClient automatically follows redirects [unless configured otherwise](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/httpagent.html)

> ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS='http.protocol.handle-redirects':  defines whether redirects should be handled automatically. This parameter expects a value of type java.lang.Boolean. If this parameter is not set HttpClient will handle redirects automatically.

Comment: Implementing this , I got the response: V/ url loaded: http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Automobile
 W/Response: Status line :HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
 url loaded: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automobile
 Response: Status line : HTTP/1.0 200 OK
 url loaded: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automobile
 Response: Status line : HTTP/1.1 200 OK (Still complete redirection isn't caught).

Comment: I opened en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Automobile.And it gets redirected to en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automobile.Probably in the server side,they are using useragent.I need to know all redirects.How could I get all these ?

Comment: Also look into this case, url loaded: http://www.autotrader.com/
Response: Status line : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 url loaded: http://m.autotrader.com/?fromwwwsite
Response: Status line : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 loaded: http://m.autotrader.com/index.html
 Response: Status line : HTTP/1.1 200 OK.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say. Yes, for some URLs you get redirects, for other - you don't get redirects. Once you turn off automatic handling you are free to do whatever you want - follow, don't follow, anything.

Comment: in case of autotrader.com, isn't it being redirected ? why am I getting status 200 .

Comment: If you are getting 200 and HANDLE_REDIRECT is turned off, then it is not redirected.

Comment: An example how to do this see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1519487/1892046 . This works for me.