# Android: Checking HTTP response code: getting 200; should be 302

Tags: java, android, http

I am checking a website for 302 messages, but I keep receiving 200 in my code:

```
private class Checker extends AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Integer>{
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        //display progressdialog.
    }

    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer ...code){
        try {
            URL u = new URL ( "http://www.reddit.com/r/notarealurlinredditqwerty");
            HttpURLConnection huc =  (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            huc.setRequestMethod("POST");
            HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
            huc.connect();
            code[0] = huc.getResponseCode();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return code[0];
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //dismiss progressdialog.
    }
}
```

That is my Async task for checking.  Here is the code implementing it:

```
int code = -1;
Checker checker = new Checker();
try {
    code = checker.execute(code).get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.d("code:", "" + code);
```

That log always returns 200, but I know that URL is 302 (it redirects to a search page on reddit.com).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://android-spirit.blogspot.in/2013/08/cosume-phppost-method-webservice-in.html watch this

Comment: It's not 302 it 404 - the page doesn't exist! but then reddit redirects you to a valid "404" page that's why you get 200 I guess.

Comment: @alfasin Actually, it is 302 because it redirects to a search page automatically.  Still, why is this giving me 200 (OK)?  That should definitely not happen.

Comment: It shows the result HTTP code of the last page you reached which is 200

Comment: You're following the redirect - so your code will get a 302, follow it, then return the status code of the first page that doesn't send a redirect.

Comment: @SamDufel How do I do that?  Can you post the code in an answer?
Is there any way not to follow the redirect?

Comment: @NightlyNexus  why `get()` in this `checker.execute(code).get()`. you should not use get() which does not make asynctask asynchronous

Comment: @Raghunandan I am trying to return a value from the AysncTask. I thought that was the best way.  Correct me if I am wrong, though.

Comment: @NightlyNexus you are wrong. Use a interface or make your asynctask an inner class of your activity class and then access data in `onPostExecute`. `get` will block the ui thread untill result is returned which you should not do.

Comment: @Raghunandan Ah, thank you.  That is much better.  Now, just have to figure out why this is still getting a code of 200.

Comment: In httpclient you need to do the following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1519487/1892046 . Don't know if it works for HttpUrlConnection though...

Answer (score 0):

This line just needs to be set to false:

```
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
```

Comment: Still getting 200.  (added right above huc.setRequestMethod("POST");)

Comment: @AlexMDC Oh, I should have clarified: I removed that line under it.  It only sets it to false-- still getting 200.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection). I have used it for response code in a few applications. I did not encounter any problems.

```
URL url = new URL("http://yoururl.com");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
int code = connection.getResponseCode();
```