# Convert short url to complete url

Tags: java, url

How to Decode and Encode a url ?
I have this short url an I want to encode that

http://test.com/en/test/93043017523/xxx-yyy-zzz

---

after a while I found this solution

java.net.URLEncoder.encode(myurl, "UTF-8");

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: 1) That is not valid Java code. You are missing quotes. 2) what is a "complete URL"?

Comment: Do you want the invert of URL shortener like goo.gl ?

Comment: see if this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519392/how-to-prevent-apache-http-client-from-following-a-redirect

You might need to do the reverse i.e. set the value to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this online tool for URL encoding: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

JS:
and also check out the built-in function encodeURIComponent(str) and encodeURI(str).
In your case, this should work:

```
var myOtherUrl = 
       "http://test.com/en/test/93043017523/" + encodeURIComponent("xxx-yyy-zzz");
```

JAVA:
In java use this URLEncoder.encode() method:

```
String url = "http://test.com/en/test/93043017523/" + URLEncoder.encode("xxx-yyy-zzz");
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpGet does not support redirects which might be causing the issue. The default behaviour is compliant with the requirements of the HTTP specification (RFC 2616)

Have you tried the [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpClient.html)? For **HttpClient 4.3** you can use the following code snippet to allow redirects:

```
HttpClient instance = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                       .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
```