# apache http client request redirect

Tags: java, apache, https, client

i am trying to access a website using https and get request using apache http client
the problem i am facing is that when i try to access my desired url from code it gives the following exception

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index: <some url>
```

but when i check it, the exception URL is not same as mine, may be it is trying to redirect it

i can more explain my scenario in the following way:

```
HttpGet get0 = new HttpGet(myurl);
CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse_g0 = httpclient.execute(get0);
```

then exception comes and states:

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index: <some other url>
```

can someone explain how this is happening and how can i control it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to this on the following question:
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/8065310/698554
actually i have to prevent redirects and capture them manually.