# How do I see which URL I was redirected to?

Tags: java, android, http

I'm trying to figure out which URL I was directed to. I'm using the following code and it seems to hide the redirect.

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

Thanks,
Erik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpClient automatically follows redirects. The only way I know of to know what redirects are going on is to introduce a RedirectHandler, as is discussed in a previous SO entry: [Preventing HttpClient 4 from following redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352949/preventing-httpclient-4-from-following-redirect).