# Correct Redirected HTTP GET retrieval

Tags: android, http, redirect, get

I'd like to know how to do a HTTP GET request to a server from which I know I will get redirected at least a couple of times...
I'd like to get the response (body) of the "last" webpage. It should come up with a code in my specific example...

Or, as an alternative, I do know you can start the browser from within your Android app, is it possible to actually retrieve the body from that ?

Any help, tips, source whatever would be helpfull, cause till now I have found (and tried) like 4 methods and to me it seems there is a jungle of HttpGet, HttpClient, HttpResponse etc libraries ?

Comment: `HttpGet`, `HttpClient`, and `HttpResponse` are classes and interfaces, not libraries.

Comment: isn't a library a collection of classes and interfaces which are supplied within a package or whatever ? An API can be a library as well or not ?

Comment: Individually, the classes aren't libraries. But since they're all packaged together, they're a library as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

```
final HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);
```

You can see more on redirect support with HttpClient in other [StackOverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352949/preventing-httpclient-4-from-following-redirect).

> is it possible to actually retrieve
>   the body from that ?

No, that would be a security violation.