# Obtaining URL from http response when no location header is sent

Tags: java, http, httpclient

When communicating with http to http://forecast.weather.gov/zipcity.php I need to obtain the URL that is generated from a request.

I have printed out the headers and their values from the http response message but there is no location header.  How can I obtain this URL?  (I'm using HttpClient)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be similar to:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpParams params = client.getParams();
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);
HttpGet method = new HttpGet("http://forecast.weather.gov/zipcity.php?inputstring=90210");
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(method);
String location = resp.getLastHeader("Location").getValue();
```

EDIT: I had to make a couple minor tweaks, but I tested and the above works.

Comment: How were you able to find that out?  I am using the .getAllHeaders() function and printing them all out and a location header was not listed.

Comment: @Petra, using LiveHttpHeaders and Firebug.  I will post an example shortly.  Which version of HttpClient are you using?

Comment: the org.apache.http.client module on Android 2.2

Comment: I downloaded those tools you mentioned and they are awesome!  It appears the first response is a redirection to the URL that I am looking for, but when I communicate with the server via HttpClient it seems to be giving me the last http response with a 200 status.  Any ideas on obtaining the header info for that very first http response message?

Comment: That looks perfect, what does the .setRedirecting() function doing?  I could look it up but since you may be active... My first guess would be that it stops all future http communication after that very first redirection response?

Comment: @Petra, that's correct.  It just tells the library not to follow the redirects on its own.  See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352949/preventing-httpclient-4-from-following-redirect/1699192#1699192); however, you don't need to create a new params object.